# How to set background color to the GroupItem in QTreeview?

Tags: c++, qt

I have created a tree view. Here i would like to set the background color of the group item. 
My implementation looks like this:

```
if (role == Qt::BackgroundRole && isCategory(index)) {
    QBrush lightGrayColor(Qt::lightGray);
    return lightGrayColor;
}
```

But the background of the icon is not colored.
[image]

If i use QTreeview:: setAlternatingColors(true) it is coloring properly. But I want to achieve in the model. Should i use QitemDelegate::paint method or can be achieved in the model itself. Thank you

Comment: The model contains the data. The view is the representation.

Comment: I meant the model class has a method data where i can set the color. Should i modify here to set the color or just use alternatingcolor call. The problem is here i want just to highlight the group items and view does not have information about it which is a groupitem

Comment: I am sorry, I can't follow. What is a _method data_?

Comment: From QAbstractItemModel::data(const QModelIndex& index, int role /*= Qt::DisplayRole*/) . Here you can use the index parameter and paint the background.

Comment: @vinaycool 
I do not see that that is handled by the model, or if you want it to be handled you will have to create your own QTreeView.

Comment: @vinaycool `setAlternatingRowColors()` or `setAlternatingColors()`?

Comment: The problem with using setAlternatingRowColors() is it will color all the items in alternative manner, so i wont be able to highlight the groupitem or provide different color to the groupitems.

Comment: @vinaycool 
then the only solution is that you create a class that inherits from QTreeView and overwrite some method that you paint, the solution is not in the delegate.